# Answering one's own question

Tags: discussion

Recently I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971042/search-for-multiple-strings-in-vqmod) question where the author appears to be well informed on the issue and answers his own question (according to SO timestamp) at precisely the same moment as he asks it.  This leads me to believe that's it's likely he asked it with the sole purpose of answering it himself - maybe as a means of disseminating info that seems useful? Or who really knows why...

My question is, is this type of thing ok and/or encouraged here?  I'm not talking about answering your own question after you've done some research and found the answer - I'm talking about asking a question you already know the answer to so you can post it.

Comment: Yes - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: **TL;DR**: that is OK, but it's hard to do well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it for sure.

[Can't help myself from quoting the below bottom-line](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

> Bottom line -- **never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site**. Please do! It's all part of our shared mission to make the internet better.

Also, see the [help center entry for self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)